# POST livewire/message{name} return 404 when in subfolder install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire project which needs (would prefer) to be installed in a subfolder of the domain `https://some-domain.com/subdir/`.

All is working fine except for the livewire route POST `/livewire/message{name}` and maybe other (not tested yet), which returns 404 or 419 in the second case.

I have tested two cases of installs.

One with all of the public folder content into the `/public_htmL/subdir/` with the index.php pointing to `/home/user/larvel-app/` which returns a 404.

The second with the subdir being a symbolic link pointing toward the `/home/user/laravel-app/public/` folder which returns a 419.

I even tried to overwrite the livewire routes without any success.

```php
Route::prefix("subdir")->group(function() {
    Route::post(
        "livewire/message/{name}", 
        "Livewire\Controllers\HttpConnectionHandler"
    );

  # Other livewire routes
});
```

Comment: Have you ensured that Livewire is actually installed?

Comment: @Qirel - Of course since the project was in dev and now trying to put into production.